# C++ overloading comparison operators vs casting operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Why don't we need to specify the return type when overloading a casting operator like bool/string

```
operator bool()
```

but we need to define the return type when overloading a comparison operator (!, >, <)

```
bool& operator ! ()
```

Why don't we define it as `bool operator bool()` instead.

Comment: `int operator bool()` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: But I would expect it to be `bool operator bool()`

Comment: comparison `operator <` might return other type than `bool`, even if unusual. As "named operator": `42 <in> container`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the actually the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`bool` *is* the return type in `operator bool()`.

Comment: I know, but why don't we need to specify the return value here (same for string)

Comment: @Ak-Mo I don't understand what that question means.

Comment: Edited the question, in short, I'm trying to understand why we don't define it as: `bool operator bool()`

Comment: @Ak-Mo Because that's redundant at best and suggests that you could put different types in the two slots at worst.